# Func<> getting the parameter info

Tags: c#, lambda, func

How to get the value of the passed parameter of the `Func<>` Lambda in C#

```
IEnumerable<AccountSummary> _data = await accountRepo.GetAsync();
string _query = "1011";
Accounts = _data.Filter(p => p.AccountNumber == _query);
```

and this is my extension method

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
        string _target = predicate.Target.ToString();
        // i want to get the value of query here.. , i expect "1011"

        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I want to get the value of **query** inside the Filter extension method assigned to **_target**

Comment: You will have to use `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` to get that info.

Comment: ok.. im trying but i cant figure out where to get it.. maybe somewhere in `predicate.Body....Right`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to get the parameter you will have to pass expression. By passing a "Func" you will pass the compiled lambda, so you cannot access the expression tree any more.

```
public static class FilterStatic
{
    // passing expression, accessing value
    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var binExpr = predicate.Body as BinaryExpression;
        var value = binExpr.Right;

        var func = predicate.Compile();
        return collection.Where(func);
    }

    // passing Func
    public static IEnumerable<T> Filter2<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return collection.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Testmethod

```
var accountList = new List<Account>
{
    new Account { Name = "Acc1" },
    new Account { Name = "Acc2" },
    new Account { Name = "Acc3" },
};
var result = accountList.Filter(p => p.Name == "Acc2");  // passing expression
var result2 = accountList.Filter2(p => p.Name == "Acc2");  // passing function
```

Answer (score 1):

so instead of passing your predicate as a `Func<T,bool>` pass an Expression tree instead `Expression<Func<T,bool>`

You can then examine what type of expression it is and get it's component parts, it won't affect how the method is called, you can still pass it a lambda.

Comment: i made it up to this.. `var _a = predicate;
            var _aa = _a.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression;
            var _r = _aa.Right;` now i want to get the value of `_r`

Comment: yep, thats the idea...but you will need to check the expression type, as it might not be a binary expression, could be a method call, or a constant etc

Comment: _r will be an expression as well, if its a constant, then you are sweet, but of course it might also be a method call, you just need to keep traversing the tree (generally you would use a visitor to do this)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think you can do that. Check following situation:

Your `predicate` is set to be `Func<T, bool> predicate`, so you can call it like that:

```
Accounts = _data.Filter(p => true);
```

What would you like to get from that kind of call?

*`(p) => true` satisfies `Func<T, bool>`, because it takes `T` as input and returns `bool` value.*

Comment: i want to get the value of `_query` so i can check if it contains a value or not..

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by Fried's answer, and found another approach to solve this:

1. Wrap the Func<T, bool> inside an Expression
2. Convert Expression.Right into Lambda function Func that will return the RHS value of the expression.

   ```
    public static void Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
       int value = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(predicate.Right).Compile().Invoke();
    }
   ```