# c# - How to change Func<T> arguments

Tags: c#, wcf

I Have the following function:

```
protected static T WrapException<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    T result = default(T);

    WrapException(delegate
    {
        result = function();
    });
    return result;
}
```

I use this function in all of my WCF Project services endpoint:

```
public List<ResultDTO> GetSomething(SessionDto sessionDto)
{
    return WrapException(() => _someFacade.Get(sessionDto));
}
```

what i need is to change the value of sessionDto at WrapException before the action is called.

I tried to access it by making the following cast:

```
((dynamic)function.Target)
```

[image]

it works fine, but when i try to access the arguments, it throws an exception.

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Obs: sorry by my english, not my native language

Comment: If you change your windows language to English before you take your screenshots your error messages should be in English. This will greatly help other people on the site to help you.

Comment: At which point do you wanna access/change `sessionDto`?

Comment: Would changing WrapException to `T WrapException<T>(Expression<Func<T>> function)` be acceptable? it makes the problem a lot easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Func<> getting the parameter info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692638/func-getting-the-parameter-info)

Comment: @stuartd i need to change the value of parameter, access it i already can.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i can try.

Comment: the exception in english say " 'object' does not contain definition to 'sessionDto' "

Comment: @khlr i need to change.

Comment: But you have shown that you cannot see the value, let alone change it - you're just seeing metadata in the watch window. As it says in the linked question - "If you want to get the parameter you will have to pass expression. By passing a "Func" you will pass the compiled lambda, so you cannot access the expression tree any more".

Comment: Note also from [How to: Modify Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546136.aspx) - "Expression trees are immutable, which means that they cannot be modified directly. To change an expression tree, you must create a copy of an existing expression tree and when you create the copy, make the required changes."

Comment: @stuartd Ok, i changed my function to Expression<Func<T>>. How can i change the value before it is invoked ?

Comment: There's an example in [Replace parameter in lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159697/replace-parameter-in-lambda-expression)

Comment: @stuartd in all of examples i found ways to change value from Expression<Func<T,object>> in my case i have only Expression<Func<T>> what is the difference

Comment: `Func<T, object>` has a parameter of type T and returns an entity of type object - `Func<T>` has no parameters and returns an entity of type T.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it is surprisingly hard to get rid of all .NET Framework localization! I failed to do it on one production server which is now spewing a mix of German and English.

Comment: I still don't understand the question - if you don't want the parameter value you've actually been given, why don't you change the caller to provide the one you want? There's not enough context about why you're trying to do this...

Comment: i need to change the parameters of the called function before it is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is, it's impossible to do this in a safe way.

You could try to edit `sessionDto` in the `Target` object. This is an auto-generated lambda closure field. This structure is not documented. It could change at any time.

Even if you make it work this is bad architecture because you are reaching into internals of another piece of code.

Probably, you should refactor your code so that it is not necessary to edit local variables of another function(!).

Comment: the problem is that i cannot change the sessionDto in Target, when i try to do this, it thrown the exeption in the last screenshot of my question. 
'Object' do not contains 'sessionDto'

Comment: You can't use dynamic to access private members. Use Reflection.

Comment: i did it, on take a look on the questions screenshot

Comment: What do you mean by that? I understand that you "did this" but it's wrong and you shouldn't do that. Use Reflection.